# Spring controller with synchronized block seems block whole method instead only block of code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, synchronized

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @GetMapping
    public String testStr(String str) {
        String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        log.info("testStr start {} {}", str, key);
        synchronized (str.intern()) {
            log.info("testStr in {} {}", str, key);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        log.info("testStr end {} {}", str, key);
        return str;
    }
}
```

When I call with two request `?str=aaa`, the log looks like this:

```
 testStr start aaa 3bbb03e3-84d9-4816-b275-de59657bd810
 testStr in aaa 3bbb03e3-84d9-4816-b275-de59657bd810
... after 5 sec
 testStr end aaa 3bbb03e3-84d9-4816-b275-de59657bd810
 testStr start aaa b4f07a65-e37e-4471-be79-877a8d529f04
 testStr in aaa b4f07a65-e37e-4471-be79-877a8d529f04
... after 5 sec
 testStr end aaa b4f07a65-e37e-4471-be79-877a8d529f04
```

But I think it should be

```
 testStr start aaa 3bbb03e3-84d9-4816-b275-de59657bd810
 testStr in aaa 3bbb03e3-84d9-4816-b275-de59657bd810
 testStr start aaa b4f07a65-e37e-4471-be79-877a8d529f04
... after 5sec
 testStr in aaa b4f07a65-e37e-4471-be79-877a8d529f04
 testStr end aaa 3bbb03e3-84d9-4816-b275-de59657bd810
... after 5 sec
 testStr end aaa b4f07a65-e37e-4471-be79-877a8d529f04
```

Different part: the `testStr start...` should be log before 5 sec.

Am I miss something?

Btw, I test these code with simple main without spring stuff then everything work as expected.

main code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoController demoController = new DemoController();
        new Thread(()->{
            String result = demoController.testStr("aaa");
            log.info("result1 {}", result);
        }).start();
        new Thread(()->{
            String result = demoController.testStr("aaa");
            log.info("result2 {}", result);
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: So you are basically saying that java doesn't know how to synchronize? As this has nothing to do with Spring nor Spring Boot but how synchronizing is applied by the JVM.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what are you saying. If this is JVM impl problem, why I got different result when run with pure main?

Comment: Main is single threaded, this is multiple threads. Syncronized is a jvm feature and how and what that blocks is up to the jvm not spring.

Comment: My main is multiple thread too, I update my question: add main class. Please check again.

Comment: Regardless, syncronized reamins a JVM thing not a spring thing. Also you are syncing on the key (well actually the result of `str.intern` and you don't know when that finishes.

Comment: How are you sending the requests? Are you actually sending the requests concurrently? Are you sure? Because most likely, the issue is the you are sending the requests one after the other.

Comment: sure, I open two chrome tab and send that.

Comment: If you try one of your 2 requests in the incognito tab and the other in the normal tab, you will get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Oops, you are right, it work. I test with Edge, it's not work, seems it's Chromium based browser only problem. I test with Firefox too, and it work without incognito tab way.